# Do not know how to output html onto a page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I've followed along with a tutorial video (112 videos in length) and so I'm quite ignorant in many aspects still when it comes to coding; although I've learned a tonne.

What I am having difficulty doing is just what the title says. In the admin panel, which I am currently working on, I have (for instance) assigned to a paragraph tag the jquery bootstrap helper class of "alert alert-success" as you can see here: `http://i1379.photobucket.com/albums/...ps44962161.png`.

The reason why it is working in the above example is because the SQL which runs upon hitting save (inserting and updating) do not require ajax.

The code being executed when INSERTING and UPDATING is in a file named "queries.php" in the config folder. It is as follows (the error handling portion of course):

```
case 'pages':

if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['submitted'] == 1) {
// POST vars    
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['title']);
$label = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['label']);
$header = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['header']);
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['body']);

if (isset($_POST['id']) AND $_POST['id'] != ''){

$action = "updated";    
// UPDATE   
$query = "UPDATE posts SET user = $_POST[user], slug = '$_POST[slug]', title = '$title', label =     '$_POST[label]', header = '$header', body = '$body' WHERE id = $_GET[id]"; 

}else{

$action = "added";  
// INSERT 
$query = "INSERT INTO posts (type, user, slug, title, label, header, body) VALUES (1, $_POST[user],  '$_POST[slug]', '$title','$label','$header','$body')";

}

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

//Error Handling    
if ($result) {
$message = '<p class = "alert alert-success">Page was '.$action.'!</p>';
}else{
$message = '<p class = "alert alert-danger">Page could not be '.$action.' because:         '.mysqli_error($dbc).'</p>';
$message .= '<p class = "alert alert-warning">Query: '.$query.'</p>'; 
}   
}

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {$opened = data_post($dbc, $_GET['id']);} 

break;
```

HOWEVER, I do not know how to get the $message variable to be echoed when DELETING a post. I'm using ajax so that the post immediately disappears from the list to the left.

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(".page-delete").on("click", function(){

var selected = $(this).attr("id");
var page_id = selected.split("del_").join("");

var confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you wanted to DELETE this page?");

if (confirmed == true) {

$.get("ajax/pages.php?id="+page_id); 

$("#page_"+page_id).remove();

};
```

...and here's the ajax:

```
include '../../config/connection.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id = $id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

if ($result) {
echo "Page Deleted.";
}   else {
"There was an error...<br>";
echo $query.'<br>';
echo mysqli_error($dbc);
}
```

Here's where I'm trying to spit out the message:

```
</div>  <!-- END col-md-3 -->

<div class="col-md-9">

<!--FORM--> 
<form role="form" action="index.php?page=pages&id=<?php echo $opened['id']; ?>" method="post">

<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>

<!-- INPUT FIELD for title -->  
<div class="form-group">

<label for="title">Page Title</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $opened['title'];?>" name="title"         id="title" placeholder="Page's Title" />

</div>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help, and I apologize for not knowing something so likely basic.

Again, thanks for reading. Peace!

Comment: In the line `$.get("ajax/pages.php?id="+page_id);`, you didn't obtain the response. Also, please narrow down your question & code.

Comment: why do you escape some data, ie `$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['title']);`, but still insert most user data directly, ie. `$query = "UPDATE posts SET user = $_POST[user],`??

Comment: Surely `$action` should be tested, not assigned, and the error message should be composed if you *don't* get a `$result`, not if you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to have a callback on you ajax get.

```
$.get("ajax/pages.php?id="+page_id, function( data ) {
    $( "#result" ).html( data );  // replaces the html in div#result
    $("#page_"+page_id).remove();
 })
```

And put your message in a html tag such as `div` so we can replace it with jquery

```
<div id="result"><?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?></div>
```

Your question is a bit all over the place and you may want to read some books on best practice.

Comment: thank you sir.  Yes, i'm a noob and could use reading, but i'm also someone who suffers from severe knuckleheadedness